# Visual Studio 2019 C# Docker debugging process attach error

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug a Linux container that runs a C#/.NET 6.0 console application from Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.11.10).

When I use Debug / Attach to Process... to connect to my running container and attach to my process, I get the error:

> Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window.
>
> Unable to find debugger script at '/home/dockeruser/.vs-debugger'

For company security purposes, I'm running my container workloads as user **dockeruser**, but I can reproduce this when I adjust my Dockerfile to run as user root. The error message changes into

> Unable to find debugger script at '/root/.vs-debugger'

Output shows

```
Unable to find debugger script at '/home/dockeruser/.vs-debugger'.


Initialization log:
Determining user folder on remote system...
Checking for existing installation of debugging tools...
Downloading debugger launcher...
Creating debugger installation folder: /home/dockeruser/.vs-debugger
Copying debugger launcher to /home/dockeruser/.vs-debugger/GetVsDbg.sh
Failed: Failed to copy files.
Unable to find debugger script at '/home/dockeruser/.vs-debugger'.
Failed: Unable to find debugger script at '/home/dockeruser/.vs-debugger'.
The program '[1] dotnet' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I can work around this by *docker exec*'ing a bash session on my container and running GetDbgVs.sh as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68950674/17273131, but its a pain to do - it feels like something is misconfigured.

I've already verified that my windows identity is a member of the windows **docker-users** group.

Comment: Hi Kevin, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Thanks, @JialeXue-MSFT - I was sitting on it in case somebody came up with the "for real" solution instead of the cheap workaround. I'll mark this as accepted in case anybody else has this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While not the answer I wanted, I've got a 1-liner shell workaround that I execute on my container when I want to debug attach with VS2019, once I know my **<CONTAINER_NAME>**. This may be useful to others with this problem.

`docker exec -u root <CONTAINER_NAME> sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install wget -y"; docker exec <CONTAINER_NAME> sh -c "mkdir -p ~/.vs-debugger; wget https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh -O ~/.vs-debugger/GetVsDbg.sh; chmod a+x ~/.vs-debugger/GetVsDbg.sh"`

- The first command installs wget as root
- The second command downloads [GetVsDbg.sh](https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh) to ~/.vs-debugger

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did not have `GetVsDbg.sh`. I just copied it from my old machine and place it under `~/.vs-debugger/GetVsDbg.sh` and it worked. The content of GetVsDbg.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.

# Working dirctory to return to
__InitialCWD=$(pwd)

# Location of the script
__ScriptDirectory=

# VsDbg Meta Version. It could be something like 'latest', 'vs2022', 'vs2019', 'vsfm-8', 'vs2017u5', or a fully specified version.
__VsDbgMetaVersion=

# Install directory of the vsdbg relative to the script.
__InstallLocation=

# When SkipDownloads is set to true, no access to internet is made.
__SkipDownloads=false

# Launches VsDbg after downloading/upgrading.
__LaunchVsDbg=false

# Mode used to launch vsdbg.
__VsDbgMode=

# Removes existing installation of VsDbg in the Install Location.
__RemoveExistingOnUpgrade=false

# Internal, fully specified version of the VsDbg. Computed when the meta version is used.
__VsDbgVersion=

__ExactVsDbgVersionUsed=false

# RuntimeID of dotnet
__RuntimeID=

# Alternative location of installed debugger
__AltInstallLocation=

# Whether to use the alternate location version of the debugger. This is set after verifying the version is up-to-date.
__UseAltDebuggerLocation=false

# Flag to indicate that we will have to download the zip version and extract it as a zip.
__UseZip=false

# Flag to indicate that we support offline installation and will report with a structured error message.
__OfflineMode=false

GetVsDbgShDataPrefix="GetVsDbgShData:"

__VsdbgCompressedFile=

# Echo a message and exit with a failure
fail()
{
    echo
    echo "$1"
    exit 1
}

# Gets the script directory
get_script_directory()
{
    scriptDirectory=$(dirname "$0")
    cd "$scriptDirectory" || fail "Command failed: 'cd \"$scriptDirectory\"'"
    __ScriptDirectory=$(pwd)
    cd "$__InitialCWD" || fail "Command failed: 'cd \"$__InitialCWD\"'"
}

print_help()
{
    echo 'GetVsDbg.sh [-usho] -v V [-l L] [-r R] [-d M] [-e E]'
    echo ''
    echo 'This script downloads and configures vsdbg, the Cross Platform .NET Debugger'
    echo '-u    Deletes the existing installation directory of the debugger before installing the current version.'
    echo '-s    Skips any steps which requires downloading from the internet.'
    echo '-d M  Launches debugger after the script completion. Where M is the mode, "mi" or "vscode"'
    echo '-h    Prints usage information.'
    echo '-v V  Version V can be "latest" or a version number such as 15.0.25930.0'
    echo '-l L  Location L where the debugger should be installed. Can be absolute or relative'
    echo '-r R  Debugger for the RuntimeID will be installed'
    echo '-a A  Specify a different alternate location that the debugger might already be installed.'
    echo '-o    Enables "Offline Mode" This enables structured output to use if the current machine does not have access to internet.'
    echo '-e E  E is the full path to the compressed package obtained from outside of the script.'
    echo ''
    echo 'For more information about using this script with Visual Studio Code see:'
    echo 'https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Attaching-to-remote-processes'
    echo ''
    echo 'For more information about using this script with Visual Studio see:'
    echo 'https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio'
    echo ''
    echo 'To report issues, see:'
    echo 'https://github.com/omnisharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues'
}

get_dotnet_runtime_id()
{
    if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ]; then
        if [ "$(uname -m)" = "arm64" ]; then
            __RuntimeID=osx-arm64
        else
            __RuntimeID=osx-x64
        fi
    elif [ "$(uname -m)" = "x86_64" ]; then
        __RuntimeID=linux-x64
        if [ -e /etc/os-release ]; then
            # '.' is the same as 'source' but is POSIX compliant
            . /etc/os-release
            if [ "$ID" = "alpine" ]; then
                __RuntimeID=linux-musl-x64
            fi
        fi
    elif [ "$(uname -m)" = "armv7l" ]; then
        __RuntimeID=linux-arm
    elif [ "$(uname -m)" = "aarch64" ]; then
         __RuntimeID=linux-arm64
         if [ -e /etc/os-release ]; then
            # '.' is the same as 'source' but is POSIX compliant
            . /etc/os-release
            if [ "$ID" = "alpine" ]; then
                __RuntimeID=linux-musl-arm64
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

remap_runtime_id()
{
    case "$__RuntimeID" in
        "debian.8-x64"|"rhel.7.2-x64"|"centos.7-x64"|"fedora.23-x64"|"opensuse.13.2-x64"|"ubuntu.14.04-x64"|"ubuntu.16.04-x64"|"ubuntu.16.10-x64"|"fedora.24-x64"|"opensuse.42.1-x64")
            __RuntimeID=linux-x64
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
}

# Parses and populates the arguments
parse_and_get_arguments()
{
    while getopts "v:l:r:d:a:suhoe:" opt; do
        case $opt in
            v)
                __VsDbgMetaVersion=$OPTARG;
                ;;
            l)
                __InstallLocation=$OPTARG
                # Subdirectories under '~/.vs-debugger' should always be safe to remove
                case $__InstallLocation in
                   "$HOME/.vs-debugger/"*)
                      __RemoveExistingOnUpgrade=true
                      ;;
                esac
                ;;
            u)
                __RemoveExistingOnUpgrade=true
                ;;
            s)
                __SkipDownloads=true
                ;;
            d)
                __LaunchVsDbg=true
                __VsDbgMode=$OPTARG
                ;;
            r)
                __RuntimeID=$OPTARG
                ;;
            a)
                __AltInstallLocation=$OPTARG
                ;;
            h)
                print_help
                exit 1
                ;;
            o)
                __OfflineMode=true
                ;;
            e)
                __VsdbgCompressedFile=$OPTARG

                # Convert to absolute path. If `cd` fails, `pwd` will not run and the subshell will exit with 1.
                __VsDbgCompressedFullPath=$(cd "$(dirname "$__VsdbgCompressedFile")" || fail "Command Failed: 'cd \"\$(dirname \"$__VsdbgCompressedFile\")\"'" ; pwd) 2>/dev/null

                # `cd` will fail within the subshell and exit with 1.
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    __VsdbgCompressedFile="$__VsDbgCompressedFullPath/$(basename "$__VsdbgCompressedFile")"
                else
                    fail "ERROR: Failed to get the absolute path to $__VsdbgCompressedFile."
                fi

                # Test to see we got an existing file.
                if [ ! -f "$__VsdbgCompressedFile" ]; then
                    fail "ERROR: The compressed file path $__VsdbgCompressedFile does not exist."
                fi
                ;;
            \?)
                echo "ERROR: Invalid Option: -$OPTARG"
                print_help
                exit 1;
                ;;
            :)
                echo "ERROR: Option expected for -$OPTARG"
                print_help
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
    done

    if [ -z "$__VsDbgMetaVersion" ]; then
        fail "ERROR: Version is not an optional parameter"
    fi

    case "$__VsDbgMetaVersion" in
        -*)
            fail "ERROR: Version should not start with hyphen"
            ;;
    esac

    case "$__AltInstallLocation" in
        -*)
            fail "ERROR: Alternate install location should not start with hyphen"
            ;;
    esac

    if [ -z "$__InstallLocation" ]; then
        fail "ERROR: Install location is not an optional parameter"
    fi

    case "$__InstallLocation" in
        -*)
            fail "ERROR: Install location should not start with hyphen"
            ;;
    esac

    if [ "$__RemoveExistingOnUpgrade" = true ]; then
        if [ "$__InstallLocation" = "$__ScriptDirectory" ]; then
            fail "ERROR: Cannot remove the directory which has the running script. InstallLocation: $__InstallLocation, ScriptDirectory: $__ScriptDirectory"
        fi

        if [ "$__InstallLocation" = "$HOME" ]; then
            fail "ERROR: Cannot remove home ( $HOME ) directory."
        fi
    fi
}

# Prints the arguments to stdout for the benefit of the user and does a quick sanity check.
print_arguments()
{
    echo "Using arguments"
    echo "    Version                    : '$__VsDbgMetaVersion'"
    echo "    Location                   : '$__InstallLocation'"
    echo "    SkipDownloads              : '$__SkipDownloads'"
    echo "    LaunchVsDbgAfter           : '$__LaunchVsDbg'"
    if [ "$__LaunchVsDbg" = true ]; then
        echo "        VsDbgMode              : '$__VsDbgMode'"
    fi
    echo "    RemoveExistingOnUpgrade    : '$__RemoveExistingOnUpgrade'"
    if [ "$__OfflineMode" = true ]; then
        echo "    OfflineMode                : '$__OfflineMode'"
    fi
    if [ -n "$__VsdbgCompressedFile" ]; then
        echo "    CompressedFileToExtract    : '$__VsdbgCompressedFile'"
    fi
}

# Prepares installation directory.
prepare_install_location()
{
    if [ -f "$__InstallLocation" ]; then
        fail "ERROR: Path '$__InstallLocation' points to a regular file and not a directory"
    elif [ ! -d "$__InstallLocation" ]; then
        echo 'Info: Creating install directory'
        if ! mkdir -p "$__InstallLocation"; then
            fail "ERROR: Unable to create install directory: '$__InstallLocation'"
        fi
    fi
}

# Checks if the debugger is already installed in the alternate location. If so, verify the version and if it matches, use it.
verify_and_use_alt_install_location()
{
    if [ -n "$__AltInstallLocation" ] && [ -d "$__AltInstallLocation" ]; then
        __AltSuccessFile="$__AltInstallLocation/success_version.txt"
        if [ -f "$__AltSuccessFile" ]; then
            __AltVersion=$(tr -cd '0-9.' < "$__AltSuccessFile")
            echo "Info: Existing debugger install found at $__AltInstallLocation'"
            echo "    Version                    : '$__AltVersion'"
            if [ "$__VsDbgVersion" = "$__AltVersion" ]; then
                __InstallLocation=$__AltInstallLocation
                __UseAltDebuggerLocation=true
                __SkipDownloads=true
                echo "Info: Using debugger found at '$__InstallLocation'"
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

# Converts relative location of the installation directory to absolute location.
convert_install_path_to_absolute()
{
    if [ -z "$__InstallLocation" ]; then
        __InstallLocation=$(pwd)
    else
        if [ ! -d "$__InstallLocation" ]; then
            prepare_install_location
        fi

        cd "$__InstallLocation" || fail "Command Failed: 'cd \"$__InstallLocation\""
        __InstallLocation=$(pwd)
        cd "$__InitialCWD" || fail "Command Failed: 'cd \"$__InitialCWD\"'"
    fi
}

# Computes the VSDBG version
set_vsdbg_version()
{
    # This case statement is done on the lower case version of version_string
    # Add new version constants here
    # 'latest' version may be updated
    # all other version contstants i.e. 'vs2017u1' or 'vs2017u5' may not be updated after they are finalized
    version_string="$(echo "$1" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')"
    case "$version_string" in
        latest)
            __VsDbgVersion=17.6.10606.1
            ;;
        vs2022)
            __VsDbgVersion=17.6.10606.1
            ;;
        vs2019)
            __VsDbgVersion=17.6.10606.1
            ;;
        vsfm-8)
            __VsDbgVersion=17.6.10606.1
            ;;
        vs2017u5)
            __VsDbgVersion=17.6.10606.1
            ;;
        vs2017u1)
            __VsDbgVersion="15.1.10630.1"
            __UseZip=true
            ;;
        [0-9]*)
            __VsDbgVersion=$1
            __ExactVsDbgVersionUsed=true

            # .tar.gz format is only avaliabe on versions higher than 16.5.20117
             __UseZip=$(echo "$__VsDbgVersion" | tr '-' '.' | awk '{split($0,a,"."); if (a[1] > 16 || (a[1] == 16 && a[2] > 5) || (a[1] == 16 && a[2] == 5 && a[3] > 20117)) {print "false"} else {print "true"};}')
            ;;
        *)
            fail "ERROR: '$1' does not look like a valid version number."
    esac
}

# Removes installation directory if remove option is specified.
process_removal()
{
    if [ "$__RemoveExistingOnUpgrade" = true ]; then

        echo "Info: Attempting to remove '$__InstallLocation'"

        if [ -d "$__InstallLocation" ]; then
            wcOutput=$(lsof "$__InstallLocation/vsdbg" | wc -l)

            if [ "$wcOutput" -gt 0 ]; then
                fail "ERROR: vsdbg is being used in location '$__InstallLocation'"
            fi

            if ! rm -rf "$__InstallLocation"; then
                fail "ERROR: files could not be removed from '$__InstallLocation'"
            fi
        fi
        echo "Info: Removed directory '$__InstallLocation'"
    else
        echo "Info: Cleaning up old files from '$__InstallLocation'."

        # Delete the old success.txt. This should always exist since we just read it.
        rm "$__InstallLocation/success.txt"

        # Old files can cause problems if the new vsdbg doesn't contain them. Remove
        # the files which may not exist in the new version.
        for i in "$__InstallLocation"/*.dll; do
            [ -f "$i" ] && rm "$i"
        done
        for i in "$__InstallLocation"/*.vsdconfig; do
            [ -f "$i" ] && rm "$i"
        done
        for i in "$__InstallLocation"/libSystem.*Native*.so; do
            [ -f "$i" ] && rm "$i"
        done
        for i in "$__InstallLocation"/libSystem.*Native*.dylib; do
            [ -f "$i" ] && rm "$i"
        done
    fi
}

# Checks if the existing copy is the latest version.
check_latest()
{
    __SuccessFile="$__InstallLocation/success.txt"
    if [ -f "$__SuccessFile" ]; then
        __LastInstalled=$(cat "$__SuccessFile")
        echo "Info: Last installed version of vsdbg is '$__LastInstalled'"
        if [ "$__VsDbgVersion" = "$__LastInstalled" ]; then
            __SkipDownloads=true
            echo "Info: VsDbg is up-to-date"
        else
            process_removal
        fi
    else
        echo "Info: Previous installation at '$__InstallLocation' not found"
    fi
}

check_internet_connection()
{
    if hash wget 2>/dev/null; then
        wget -q --spider "$1"
    elif hash curl 2>/dev/null; then
        curl -Is "$1" | head -1 | grep 200
    else
        if [ "$__OfflineMode" = true ]; then
            echo "${GetVsDbgShDataPrefix}URL=$url"
        fi
        fail "ERROR: Unable to find 'wget' or 'curl'. Install 'curl' or 'wget'. It is needed to download the vsdbg package."
    fi

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        if [ "$__OfflineMode" = true ]; then
            echo "${GetVsDbgShDataPrefix}URL=$url"
        fi
        fail "ERROR: No internet connection."
    fi
}

download()
{
    if [ "$__UseZip" = false ]; then
        vsdbgFileExtension=".tar.gz"
    else
        echo "Warning: Version '${__VsDbgMetaVersion}' is only avaliable in zip."
        vsdbgFileExtension=".zip"
    fi
    vsdbgCompressedFile="vsdbg-${__RuntimeID}${vsdbgFileExtension}"
    target="$(echo "${__VsDbgVersion}" | tr '.' '-')"
    url="https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/vsdbg-${target}/${vsdbgCompressedFile}"

    check_internet_connection "$url"

    echo "Downloading ${url}"
    if hash wget 2>/dev/null; then
        wget -q "$url" -O "$vsdbgCompressedFile"
    elif hash curl 2>/dev/null; then
        curl -s "$url" -o "$vsdbgCompressedFile"
    fi

    if [ $? -ne  0 ]; then
        echo
        echo "ERROR: Could not download ${url}"
        exit 1;
    fi

    __VsdbgCompressedFile=$vsdbgCompressedFile
}

extract()
{
    errorMessage=
    if [ "$__UseZip" = false ]; then
        if ! hash tar 2>/dev/null; then
            errorMessage="ERROR: Failed to find 'tar'."
        elif ! tar -xzf "$__VsdbgCompressedFile"; then
            errorMessage="ERROR: Failed to extract vsdbg."
        fi
    else
        if ! hash unzip 2>/dev/null; then
            errorMessage="ERROR: Failed to find 'zip'."
        elif ! unzip -o -q "$__VsdbgCompressedFile"; then
            errorMessage="ERROR: Failed to unzip vsdbg."
        fi
    fi

    # If no errors, continue
    if [ -z "$errorMessage" ]; then
        chmod +x ./vsdbg
        # Check to see if vsdbg has execute permissions.
        if [ ! -x ./vsdbg ]; then
            errorMessage="ERROR: Failed to set executable permissions on vsdbg."
        fi
    fi

    rm "$__VsdbgCompressedFile"

    # Error occured, cleanup the compressed binary and exit with error.
    if [ -n "$errorMessage" ]; then
        fail "$errorMessage"
    fi
}

get_script_directory

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Missing arguments for GetVsDbg.sh"
    print_help
    exit 1
else
    parse_and_get_arguments "$@"
fi

set_vsdbg_version "$__VsDbgMetaVersion"

check_latest
# only try and use the alternate debugger location if the one in the default location is not adequate
if [ "$__SkipDownloads" = false ]; then
    verify_and_use_alt_install_location
fi

echo "Info: Using vsdbg version '$__VsDbgVersion'"
convert_install_path_to_absolute
print_arguments

# Shortcut if we are using Alternate Debugger Location
if [ "$__UseAltDebuggerLocation" = false ]; then
    if [ "$__SkipDownloads" = true ]; then
        echo "Info: Skipping downloads"
    else
        prepare_install_location
        cd "$__InstallLocation" || fail "Command failed: 'cd \"$__InstallLocation\"'"

        # For the rest of this script we can assume the working directory is the install path

        # Check to see if we already have a compressed file to extract, if not, we need to download it.
        if [ -z "$__VsdbgCompressedFile" ]; then
            if [ -z "$__RuntimeID" ]; then
                get_dotnet_runtime_id
            elif [ "$__ExactVsDbgVersionUsed" = "false" ]; then
                # Remap the old distro-specific runtime ids unless the caller specified an exact build number.
                # We don't do this in the exact build number case so that old builds can be used.
                remap_runtime_id
            fi

            echo "Info: Using Runtime ID '$__RuntimeID'"
            download
        fi

        extract

        echo "$__VsDbgVersion" > success.txt
        # per greggm, this 'cd' can fail sometimes and is to be expected.
        # shellcheck disable=SC2164
        cd "$__InitialCWD"
        echo "Info: Successfully installed vsdbg at '$__InstallLocation'"
    fi
fi

if [ "$__LaunchVsDbg" = true ]; then
    # Note: The following echo is a token to indicate the vsdbg is getting launched.
    # If you were to change or remove this echo make the necessary changes in the MIEngine
    echo "Info: Launching vsdbg"
    "$__InstallLocation/vsdbg" "--interpreter=$__VsDbgMode"
    exit $?
fi

exit 0
```